# Pass several variables from Smarty to PHP function

Tags: php, smarty

We got a shopsystem working with Smarty. I need to pass some Smarty variables to a PHP function and get the return.

What I know and also did so far is the following:

```
{$order_id|@get_order_total}
```

So this passes the Smarty Variable "`$order_id`" to a included PHP file which contains the function `get_order_total($order_id)` and shows me the return of this function.

Now I need to pass 3 variables to a PHP function. The function would for example look like this:

```
handleDebit($order, $payCode, $insertId)
```

Sadly i have not found the right thing so far in smarty documentation. Anyone has ever done this?

Comment: Question. Why are you doing this from smarty at all and not dealing with it in your controller (or whatever you're using)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to call the function from within smarty templates, register a wrapper function as smarty-plugin:

```
<?php
$smarty->registerPlugin("function","handleDebit", "handleDebitSmarty");

function handleDebitSmarty($params, $smarty)
{
  return handleDebit($params['order'], $params['payCode'], $params['insertId']); 
}
```

Now you can use it as smarty tag:

```
{handleDebit order=$blah payCode=$blub insertId=$yeahh}
```

But you should consider @JonSterling s advice and try to find a way auch that a controller is doing the `handleDebit`-call and you only handle results/display-stuff in the template.